# Чувствительность к регистру при запросе mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

здравствуйте, есть запрос

```
select id from users where user = 'Test'
```

который не видит пользователя с ником test, как можно это исправить? На старом сервере такой проблемы не было

сейчас стоит Centos 7, php7, pma, mariadb

Comment: `такой проблемы не было` - ты считаешь, что выборка с чувствительностью - проблема? То есть например если хочешь дать админские права человеку и выбрал случайно не по `id`, а по имени и вместо `Test` выбрался `test` - это норма?

Comment: вот именно, с такой кодировкой разных не нужных пользователей на подобии "test" и "Test" не будет, будет только 1, и тут не ошибешься

Comment: Кстати такой подход использует Windows (было время когда даже пароли были регистронезависимыми), но лично мне это также не нравится как и Алексею. Не хотите чтобы были такие клоны (использование регистронезависимого сравнения при регистрации) - это одно дело, но пускать пользователя в другом регистре - плохо

Comment: я наоборот не хочу пускать пользователя с другим регистром, раньше Test и test были разные логины, и могла возникнуть путоница, и я специально задал вопрос, чтобы устранить возможность регистрации ников к примеру Admin aDmin и тд

Answer (score 3):

В MySQL сравнение строк производится с учетом правил сравнения (COLLATE) заданным для базы, таблицы, поля или в самом запросе. Понять как будет происходит сравнение просто: если кодировка задана правильно и в COLLATE есть суффикс `_ci` (case insensitive) - при сравнении символы в разном регистре будут считаться одинаковыми, если `_cs` (case sensitive) или `_bin` - сравнение будет строгим

См. также:

- [Character Sets and Collations in General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) (Кодировки и правила сравнения в общем случае) (на английском)
- [Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) (Использование правил сравнения в запросах) (на английском)

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло, а ещё не подскажите как изменить кодировку базы данных, таблиц, и столбцов, вообщем полностью всё вместе, одним запросом? ибо я изменил в нужном столбце, а во всём остальном осталось _bin, а в ручную менять как то глупо

Comment: @turik97 В базе можно установить по-умолчанию через ALTER DATABASE, но существующие таблицы это не затронет. Поменять в отдельной таблице все поля на определенный COLLATE (и кодировку) позволит запрос `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET ... COLLATE ...;`

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию поиск в MySQL является независимым от регистра символов (хотя существуют некоторые кодировки, которые всегда чувствительны к регистру, такие как czech). Это означает, что при поиске с помощью col_name LIKE 'a%' будут выданы все значения столбца, начинающиеся на A или a. Если необходимо выполнить тот же поиск с учетом регистра, для проверки префикса следует использовать что-то вроде INSTR(col_name, "A")=1 или STRCMP(col_name, "A") = 0, если значение в столбце точно равно A.

Простые операции сравнения (`>=, >, =, <, <=, сортировка и группировка`) основываются на "сорте" каждого символа. Символы одного сорта (`такие как E, e и E`) обрабатываются как одинаковые символы!

В старых версиях MySQL сравнения по LIKE выполнялись над символами, переведенными в верхний регистр (`E == e, но E <> E`). В новых версиях MySQL LIKE работает точно так же, как другие операторы сравнения.

Если необходимо, чтобы столбец всегда обрабатывался в с учетом регистра, объявите его с типом BINARY.

Comment: прочтите вон [соседний ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675045/223826) про `COLLATE` много нового узнаете

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan если не поняли не значит не прав.

Comment: ваши варианты, конечно, будут работать, просто это лютые костыли. На каждый из которых отвечает `collate`, либо в теле запроса при выборке, либо в при `create/alter` таблицы. Последний абзац про binary поле для строки, это конечно вообще нонсенс.